# How to save any chart to a svg or png file

Tags: r, svg, shiny, save, png

I want to save a rendered graphic to svg or png.

Here is the ui and server code:

UI

```
library(shiny)
library(echarts4r)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("add", "Add Data to y"),
  echarts4rOutput("plot"),
  verbatimTextOutput("selected")
)
```

server

```
server <- function(input, output, session){

  data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10, 5, 3), y = rnorm(10, 50, 12), z = rnorm(10, 50, 5))
  
  react <- eventReactive(input$add, {
    set.seed(sample(1:1000, 1))
    data.frame(x = rnorm(10, 5, 2), y = rnorm(10, 50, 10))
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderEcharts4r({
    data |> 
     e_charts(x) |> 
     e_scatter(y) |>
     e_scatter(z) |> 
     e_brush(throttleDelay = 1000)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$add, {
    echarts4rProxy("plot") |> 
      e_append1_p(0, react(), x, y)
  })
  
  output$selected <- renderPrint({
    input$plot_brush
  })
  
}
```

I need to save these charts in a svg or png file on my machine using R code.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer are found in [packages' documentation pages](https://echarts4r.john-coene.com/articles/toolbox.html)

The `echarts4r` package has a [toolbox](https://echarts4r.john-coene.com/reference/toolbox.html) with several features, such as `saveAsImage`.

Just add to the `renderEcharts4r` call:

```
  output$plot <- renderEcharts4r({
    data |> 
      e_charts(x) |> 
      e_scatter(y) |>
      e_scatter(z) |> 
      e_brush(throttleDelay = 1000) |> 
      e_toolbox_feature(feature = "saveAsImage")
  })
```

Comment: Hello GGamba. Thanks for the quick response. However, I am looking for something that is automatic. I want the image to be downloaded automatically in my current drive location as I will use these images to place them in a Rmarkdown pdf. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: They are "interactive" graph, not simple images, when would you want to automatically download it?

Comment: Once the charts are rendered, I want to download them to my directory automatically.

Comment: If you are interested in static images only (or rather, reactive to inputs in the apps), I'd use `ggplot2` and its `ggsave` function.